# Estimate ratio of two gamma functions when individual functions return inf value

Tags: python, scipy, inf, gamma

I'm estimating the ratio of two gamma functions. Both estimates for `gamma(x)` and `gamma(y)` are very large ( > 10^300) but the ratio of the two should be fairly small.

```
from scipy.special import gamma
gamma(x) / gamma(y)
```

Unfortunately, there is a point where `gamma(x)` is too large and the scipy returns an `inf` value. Is there a way to stop this, increase the threshold, or alternatively calculate this ratio?

Thanks

Comment: Are x, y real or complex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming x and y are real and positive you can use the following identity:

```
a / b = e^(ln(a) - ln(b))
```

I can suggest using `gmpy2` for the arbitrary precision calculation. It has `gmpy2.lgamma`, which returns the logarithm of the gamma function, and you can use `gmpy2.exp` to convert from the logarithm form to your desired ratio.

Comment: `scipy.special` has `gammaln` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.gammaln.html), so `exp(gammaln(a) - gammaln(b))` should work.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser No, `scipy.special`'s data type is a `double`, so it can't handle the big numbers the OP requires.

Comment: Right, that's the point of using `gammaln`.  The OP says `gamma(x)` is greater than 1e300, but doesn't say how much greater.  Suppose `x` is, say, 425, and `y` is 420. Both `gamma(x)` and `gamma(y)` are much greater than 1e300 (and far exceed the maximum 64 bit floating point value), but `exp(gammaln(x) - gammaln(y))` is easily computed using 64 bit floating point to be `1.3883e13`.  How far one can go with 64 bit floating point depends on how big `x` and `y` really are, and on how big the ratio of `gamma(x)/gamma(y)` is.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Oh, I assumed `x` was on the order of 10^300. Misread. If your `x` and `y` fit in a double, feel free to use the scipy function.