# How do I get the value of gamma function in Python for large complex argument?

Tags: python, scipy, gamma-function

I am trying to compute the value of *Beta* function for complex argument. The method `scipy.special.beta` does not accept complex argument, so I defined instead

```py
beta = lambda a, b: (gamma(a) * gamma(b)) / gamma(a + b)
```

It works fine for small values, however, for large values, it would return `nan`. So I digged into the behaviour of *Gamma* function

```py
from scipy.special import gamma
import numpy
radius = 165
phi = (3.0 * numpy.pi) / 4.0
n = 1.9 + numpy.exp(phi * 1j) * radius
print gamma(n)
```

A `0j` will be returned and clearly the value is too small to be printed.

However, though the value of the *Gamma* function is super small, the value of the corresponding *Beta* function is not quite. So it still makes sense to do the calculation. But I could not figure out a way.

I tried `math.gamma`, but it would not accept complex argument. I tried the method provided in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32507888/6037395), it would return `-0j` for

```py
n = 1.9 + numpy.exp(phi * 1j) * radius
numpy.exp(numpy.log(gamma(n)) + numpy.log(gamma(0.5)) - numpy.log(gamma(n + 0.5)))
```

where I was trying to compute *beta(n, 0.5)*.

Could someone please help me on this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about scipy, but you could use [sympy](https://sympy.org/) for the evaluation of the beta function. It supports complex arguments. [This](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/special.html#sympy.functions.special.beta_functions.beta) documentation might help you with that.

So your code would roughly look like this if I understood you correctly:

```
from sympy.functions.special.beta_functions import beta
import numpy
radius = 165
phi = (3.0 * numpy.pi) / 4.0
n = 1.9 + numpy.exp(phi * 1j) * radius

print(beta(n, 0.5))
```

**>>> 0.0534468376932947 - 0.127743871500741*I**

Comment: It works great! The only thing is, how do I make sure the function `beta` is returning imaginary with `j` instead of `I`? It seems hard to manipulate the result.

Comment: simple: cast to str via `s = str(beta..))` and do a `s.replace("I", "j")`. Dirty but works. Alternatively just `complex(beta(...))` this converts to python complex type.